# DateField in Django missing Hours, Minutes, Seconds

Tags: django, oracle

I have a `Date` field in an oracle 12c legacy table which has data like `18-JAN-14 12 34 59`. 
In my django 1.10 app I have a corresponding model with a field `time = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)`. The problem is when I examine an instance of the model I get something like `datetime.date(2014, 1, 18)`....what happened to the hours, minutes, and seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should use [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) if you want to store time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `models.DateTimeField()`